# zookeeper:myid file is misssing

Tags: apache-zookeeper

## env:

macos

zookeeper3.6.1

### problem:

I can run **stand alone** mode but when I start the cluster(include 3 nodes) It throws the error:

```
  org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig$ConfigException: Error processing /Volumes/苹果存储盘/zookeeper/zookeeper2181/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:197)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:124)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: myid file is missing
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.checkValidity(QuorumPeerConfig.java:810)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.setupQuorumPeerConfig(QuorumPeerConfig.java:681)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parseProperties(QuorumPeerConfig.java:506)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerConfig.parse(QuorumPeerConfig.java:193)
    ... 2 more
```

The point is, **I've created myid file** in the data directory, and I've written the correct value in myid.

eg:

```
cd/Volumes/苹果存储盘/zookeeper/zookeeper2181/data

echo "1" > myid
```

But it still throws this error. I can make sure the position of myid file is correct

Comment: Do you have properly configures ensembles in the zoo.cfg (`server.ID=host:port`)? Do ids are unique? Is `/Volumes/苹果存储盘/zookeeper/zookeeper2181/data` configured as your dataDir in the zoo.cfg?

Comment: Of course. I can make sure my config is correct.Here is my config:                                


`dataDir=/Volumes/苹果存储盘/zookeeper/zookeeper2181/data`
`dataLogDir=/Volumes/苹果存储盘/zookeeper/zookeeper2181/logs`



`clientPort=2181`

`server.1=127.0.0.1:2287:3387
server.2=127.0.0.1:2288:3388
server.3=127.0.0.1:2289:3389`

Comment: When I start the first node.It throws the above exception.It can't find myid file.I am sure,I have created myid file under the data directory.

Comment: I solve the problem now.It's because the path of myid including Chinese.Because of Chinese data path,It can't find myid file.

Answer (score 0):

simply create a file with name `myid` in Zookeeper Data Dir (you can check it's location in zookeeper config file) and place the id of this server into it.

for example, for server with id 1 we can do this by :

```sh
echo "1" > /var/zookeeper/myid
```